# Display stock performance in android

Tags: android, graph, yahoo-finance

Could anyone please advise me what would be the best way to display the performance of a particular stock in an android app. I would be interested to know if any one has used any particular libraries.

I use a yahoo finance CSV parser to fetch the stock info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any good libraries specifically dealing with stock information, but I am assuming you are interested in charting?  There are a bunch of options for producing charts for Android apps:

[Graphview](http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview) - A custom View for creating graphs in Android

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) - A jQuery library for creating graphs. There are [one](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing) or [two](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/2010/10/13/generating-graphs-in-android.html) good tutorials for Android.

[AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/index.html) - Another charting library for Android

aiCharts seems pretty polished, and has a [free financial demo app](https://market.android.com/details?id=aiCharts.Demo.Financial) you can download from the market, but you need to buy a license to use it.  Also at the time I am writing this, their website (www.artfulbits.com) is down.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. I'm interested in charting. Thanks a lot for your help!