# Scaling Android Canvas 2D graphics for different devices

Tags: android

I asked a similar question to this awhile back and got zero responses, so I'm going to try rephrasing it . . .

What is "best practice" for ensuring that the 2D drawing primitives in the Canvas class scale properly for different devices (phones with different screen resolutions)?    Are they supposed to scale automatically?    Is there a way to scale the whole canvas?   Am I supposed to detect the size and do my own scaling as I draw each line, circle and point individually?  Am I supposed to do it by manipulating the View?  Or what?

The goal is to make sure the graphics fill up the screen to take full advantage of the available resolution,  but don't overflow it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do it in my app is by keeping track of the size of my `View`:

```
@Override 
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
  //do some calculations with width and height
}
```

Then whenever I need to manually draw something, I do it in terms of a percentage of the total resolution.  Your mileage may vary depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean you do it as "a percentage of the total resolution"?  Do you mean you programmatically adjust the length of lines, diameters of circles, sizes of dots as you draw each of them?    I'm drawing charts, graphs, and other representations of statistical and medical data.  I though about doing this but I wanted to make sure Android didn't already have a device-independent coordinate system for 2D drawing.

Comment: That's what he means yes. Android's coordinate system is not device-independent.

Comment: On a side note, since you are drawing charts and graphs, you might be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979444/display-stock-performance-in-android/4979718#4979718

Comment: Thanks.   Some of the stuff I'm doing is pretty specialized, and some of it will be actual medical data, e.g ECGs.  It's quite surprising to me that Android, which naturally operates in a highly multi-resolution environment, doesn't have a resolution independent 2D graphics library!